# What is the Big-O of a TreeSet with a comparator?

Tags: java, performance, big-o

I'm using it to sort Objects based on particular attributes of each object (ex: date and quantity). When I attach a comparator to a `TreeSet`, what type of performance will I be getting when I add N values into it and letting it self-sort?

Comment: The close reason given makes zero sense. Please be sure to review questions in the queue properly rather than blowing through them. Also, while it's true that this question lacks research, that is not a close reason in itself. I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), emphasis mine:

> This implementation provides guaranteed **log(n)** time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Your choice of comparator does not matter assuming your comparator is O(1) with respect to the size of the set (which it generally is).

The number of values you are inserting is not relevant to the complexity analysis of the insert operation itself.